# Yii2 rules in routing section

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii-routing

I am new to Yii2 and currently, I am receiving an error while setting up the application.
I try to use friendly URL.

According to the [DOCS](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing)

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'enableStrictParsing' => false,
    'rules' => [
        //... rules ...
    ]
]
```

I set this section in my application as:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'enableStrictParsing' => false,
    'rules' => [
        '/' => 'site/index',
        '/entry' => 'site/entry',
        'defaultRoute' => 'main/index'
    ]
]
```

This worked fine when I try to open URL http://yii2/entry.

If i set as:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'enableStrictParsing' => false,
    'rules' => [
        '/' => 'site/index',
        '/entry' => 'site/entry',
        'defaultRoute' => 'main/index'
    ]
]
```

If I try to open URL http://yii2/site/entry I received error `404`.

Also, if i set:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'enableStrictParsing' => false,
    'rules' => [
        '/' => 'site/index',
        '<controller>/<action>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        'defaultRoute' => 'main/index'
    ]
]
```

If i try to open url http://yii2/site/entry I received error 404 too.

Why is it happening? Where I can read more detail about routing in yii2? Where is my error?

UPD:
Apache2.2 (win) 
.htaccess contain:

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
# if $showScriptName is false in UrlManager, do not allow accessing URLs with script name
RewriteRule ^index.php/ - [L,R=404]
```

UPD2:
i receive 2 variant of 404 error: when try to use routing rule:

[image]
and when i'm using url not in rules array:
[image]

Comment: Have you got rewriting set up for your server? And which one is it, Apache, Nginx, something else?

Comment: Yes, i'm using .htaccess for rewrite.

Comment: Could you paste it here?

Comment: I updated main post. Section UPD.

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious - `http://yii2/entry` gives you result of `actionEntry()` method from `SiteController`? Have you checked Apache logs and Yii logs?

Comment: Yes actionEntry present in SiteController.

Comment: In error_log of Apache not present any errors.
access log: 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Dec/2018:22:38:36 +0300] "GET /site/entry HTTP/1.1" 404 1060

Comment: app.log is clean. I try to add : 'log' => [
        'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                'maxLogFiles' => 10
            ],
        ],
    ],
but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your rewrite rules.

Move line

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/ - [L,R=404]
```

to be the first one after `RewriteEngine on`.

**Or** add "last" flag (`[L]`) to:

```
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Without this rules processing continues to next one.